# Printing different types of attributes and listing all App elements for the selected type in Group Element by Python

Tags: python, xml

Sorry for misunderstanding title, but I couldn't explained my issue in a small title. It's not a big problem but confusing anyway.

Current output:

```
1) Deployment
2) Service Status
3) List Servers
4) Restart Service
5) Restart Server
6) Execute Commands on Servers
Make your choice: 4

1) Group
2) Single Machine
Group or Single Machine?: 1

1) The Perfect Life
Which group?: 1

1) Tomcat
1) JBoss
2) Tomcat
1) JBoss
2) Tomcat
1) JBoss
Select a service: --????--*
```

XML:

```
    <Group id="1" name="The Perfect Life"
        username="root" password="mypasswd123" state="ok">

        <Server id="1" name="Machine (250)" ip="192.168.1.250" username="" password="" state="ok">
            <App id="1" type="Tomcat" state="ok" />
        </Server>

        <Server id="2" name="Machine (251)" ip="192.168.1.251" username="" password="" state="ok">
            <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok" />
            <App id="2" type="Tomcat" path="" state="ok" />
        </Server>

        <Server id="3" name="Machine (252)" ip="192.168.1.252" username="" password="" state="ok">
            <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok" />
            <App id="2" type="Tomcat" path="" state="ok" />
        </Server>

        <Server id="4" name="Machine (253)" ip="192.168.1.253" username="" password="" state="ok">
            <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok" />
        </Server>

    </Group>
```

Code to retrieve the unfunctional "Select a service" part:

```
if GroupList:
    for App in Group.getElementsByTagName('App'):
        print App.getAttribute('id')+") "+App.getAttribute('type')

    sList = raw_input("Select a service: ")
    App = Group.getElementsByTagName('App')[int(sList)-1]

    print (' ')

    if sList:
            x = App.getAttribute('state')
            stype = App.getAttribute('type')
            trigger = 0

            while trigger < 1:
                if x == 'ok':
                    try:
                        getDeployPath = App.getAttribute('path')
                        sIP = Server.getAttribute('ip')
                        sUSER = Server.getAttribute('username')
                        sPASS = Server.getAttribute('password')

                        if not sUSER:
                            sUSER = Group.getAttribute('username')

                        if not sPASS:
                            sPASS = Group.getAttribute('password')

                        dssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
                        dssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                        dssh.connect(sIP, username=sUSER, password=sPASS)

And it goes...
...
...
```

So, what I want to do?

1) I want to, print Tomcat and JBoss (or when I add a new App to XML, print it) briefly printing different types.

2) After a selection made, select all App Tags for the Selected Service Type under all **Group Servers**. Because I will add more groups.

I tryed everything by myself. Tryed grouping them with key, but after selection I'm stuck.

**NOTE: I'm using Python's default minidom library. Not lxml or something else.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what you're asking. I'm also confused by your XML schema.

However, I would recommend that you familiarise yourself with [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp). My preferred XML lib is [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

You can use `xpath expressions` to query your XML data. The biggest caveat is that your XML may not comply with your desired data model. You ought to enforce compliance with an XML Schema and/or do a lot of manual error checking.

Here's a simple (no input checking) example of using XPATH expressions to query your XML blob. I'm selecting the group by id, but you could leave out predicate after group if you wanted to select across all groups:

```py
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML("""
<Group id="1" name="The Perfect Life"
    username="root" password="mypasswd123" state="ok">
    <Server id="1" name="Machine (250)" ip="192.168.1.250" username="" password="" state="ok">
        <App id="1" type="Tomcat" state="ok" />
    </Server>
    <Server id="2" name="Machine (251)" ip="192.168.1.251" username="" password="" state="ok">
        <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok" />
        <App id="2" type="Tomcat" path="" state="ok" />
    </Server>
    <Server id="3" name="Machine (252)" ip="192.168.1.252" username="" password="" state="ok">
        <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok" />
        <App id="2" type="Tomcat" path="" state="ok" />
    </Server>
    <Server id="4" name="Machine (253)" ip="192.168.1.253" username="" password="" state="ok">
        <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok" />
    </Server>
</Group>
""")

# group id from user
group_id = "1"
# unique apps under group_id
app_types = set(doc.xpath('//Group[@id=$group_id]/descendant::App/@type',group_id=group_id))
app_dict = dict((x+1,y) for (x,y) in enumerate(app_types))

print "Apps:\n\t" + "\n\t".join("%d) %s" % x for x in sorted(app_dict.items()))
app_selection = input("Select a service: ")
app_type = app_dict.get(int(app_selection))

# Servers in group_id with app_type
for server in doc.xpath('//Group[@id=$group_id]/Server[./App[@type=$app_type]]',group_id=group_id,app_type=app_type):
  print etree.tostring(server) # Don't know what you want to do per-server...
```

Yields:

```xml
Apps:
        1) JBoss
        2) Tomcat
Select a service: 1

<Server id="2" name="Machine (251)" ip="192.168.1.251" username="" password="" state="ok">
        <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok"/>
        <App id="2" type="Tomcat" path="" state="ok"/>
    </Server>

<Server id="3" name="Machine (252)" ip="192.168.1.252" username="" password="" state="ok">
        <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok"/>
        <App id="2" type="Tomcat" path="" state="ok"/>
    </Server>

<Server id="4" name="Machine (253)" ip="192.168.1.253" username="" password="" state="ok">
        <App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok"/>
    </Server>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with lxml, I'm using python default xml.minidom. My XML schema is the best like this. As a tree; First tag for server groups. Second tag for the server in a specified group. And the App tag for Applications running under the server. I really don't understand how people aren't understood my question. It's very simple question. Let me explain again: I'm on 2 focus. One of it, Select all App Elements in Specified Group. (As in example, All App Elements for "The Perfect Life") print the different App types. (JBoss and Tomcat [For Now])

Comment: Second Focus: After a selection made (E.G. JBoss) Print all App Elements for JBoss in the Specified Group (All JBoss Attributed App Elements in The "Perfect Life") Thats it. @MattH

Comment: Well, I think my solution does what you asked for

Comment: But its lxml and all my structure is based on minidom

Comment: Your question didn't limit preferred answers to minidom. You asked for help. Help has been offered. You're welcome

Comment: Thank you anyway, I will update my question now. Sorry for that misunderstanding

Comment: As far as I know, minidom doesn't support XPATH. [This page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml) has an overview of XML (and XPATH) support in Python. If you're extracting data from XML on a regular basis, I strongly recommend using XPATH.

Comment: Is it possible to make this extract without XPath? @MattH